# Why Python script result same as sequential processing not actual Multi threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

The term "sequential processing" refers to the completion of one task before moving on to the next.
However, multithreading processing begins at separate times, but the results should be displayed first for first completed process.

for below code getting result in sequential way(same as for loop).

```
import threading

Supplier_list = [20, 10, 5, 3, 1]
# Supplier_list = [200000, 100000, 500000, 900000, 50000]

def thread_function(max):
    x=0
    for x in range(0, max):
       # if x > max-1:
            print(x)
    print('Supplier and loop run %d times', (x, max))


def run_item(f, item):
    result_info = [threading.Event(), None]
    def runit():
        result_info[1] = f(item)
        result_info[0].set()
    threading.Thread(target=runit).start()
    return result_info

# def gather_results(result_infos):
#     results = []
#     for i in xrange(len(result_infos)):
#         result_infos[i][0].wait()
#         results.append(result_infos[i][1])
#     return results

result_infos = [run_item(thread_function, item) for item in Supplier_list]

# results = gather_results(result_infos)
```

In this code, all of the points are printed, however the final value in the list thread should be completed first and the result displayed first.

Comment: The threads can run in any order. Why do you think the final value should be completed first?

Comment: @countunique Because the last value is lower, it takes less time to process than the other entries in the list, hence it should be completed first and the result passed first.

Comment: That's actually not true. The scheduling of threads is handled by the operating system and there's no guarantee that a thread will finish before another thread just because it has less work to do.